# PushSharp and Background task

Tags: multithreading, pushsharp

I have been using PushSharp during these last 4 years without too much trouble, and I lately experience problems when sending to more than one device at a time. I was wondering if in a Web environment there is a need to run the PushSharp process in a separate thread in the background or if PushSharp will do that anyway. The reason is that if a web page triggers the push, it will kill the thread as soon as it finishes (although framework 4.5.2 introduced QueueBackgroundWorkItem that will continue to run, but I could not see any difference). On the second hand if the PushSharp task takes too long it will keep the web page busy for an unnecessary time that may be long if there a lot of notifications to send.

Comment: What is your actual question? If it is about whether PushSharp uses asynchronous methods for sending notifications, the answer is yes.

Comment: This is indeed the question but what happens if the page that triggered PushSharp ends before all notifications are sent. Does PushSharp runs in a process of its own or is it dependent on the process that launched it?

Comment: this depends entirely on what you mean by "page".

Comment: In my case a smartphone calls a web page to send a notification to several smartphones. This is a brief call and the web page does a very few except calling PushSharp